# Parsing JSON data with a period from ALPHA VANTAGE VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am trying to parse data from alpha vantage but the properties inside of objects have a period in them causing it to return nothing.

```
    Public Sub GetPKGStats(symbol As String)
        Dim StatsUrl, result, Open, Close, Volume, LastRefreshed As String
        Dim JSONresult As JObject     
        Dim results As List(Of JToken)

        result = "{""Meta Data"": {""1. Information"": ""Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes"",""2. Symbol"": ""PKG"",""3. Last Refreshed"": ""2021-02-16"",""4. Output Size"": ""Compact"",""5. Time Zone"": ""US/Eastern""},""Time Series (Daily)"": {""2021-02-16"": {""1. open"": ""133.4500"",""2. high"": ""133.5650"",""3. low"": ""131.5000"",""4. close"": ""133.0400"",""5. volume"": ""638371""},""2021-02-12"": {""1. open"": ""131.0400"",""2. high"": ""133.9200"",""3. low"": ""131.0400"",""4. close"": ""133.1800"",""5. volume"": ""562984""},""2021-02-11"": {""1. open"": ""133.9900"",""2. high"": ""134.4900"",""3. low"": ""130.3700"",""4. close"": ""131.1700"",""5. volume"": ""768588""}}}"
    JSONresult = JObject.Parse(result)   
    results = JSONresult.Children().ToList()

     For each item As JProperty In results
         LastRefreshed =  item.First.SelectToken("1.Information")
     Next    
End Sub
```

This does not return anything, but if i remove the period from the first property of the "Meta Data" Object, returns just fine. i was thinking about doing a replacing onthe returned string for the period but this may affect the values if they have a period in them.

this is a shortened JSON string example.

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "PKG",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-02-16",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2021-02-16": {
        "1. open": "133.4500",
        "2. high": "133.5650",
        "3. low": "131.5000",
        "4. close": "133.0400",
        "5. volume": "638371"
    },
    "2021-02-12": {
        "1. open": "131.0400",
        "2. high": "133.9200",
        "3. low": "131.0400",
        "4. close": "133.1800",
        "5. volume": "562984"
    },
    "2021-02-11": {
        "1. open": "133.9900",
        "2. high": "134.4900",
        "3. low": "130.3700",
        "4. close": "131.1700",
        "5. volume": "768588"
    },
    "2021-02-10": {
        "1. open": "132.9800",
        "2. high": "134.1200",
        "3. low": "132.5200",
        "4. close": "133.7900",
        "5. volume": "715949"
    }
  }
}
```

is there a way to alter the property names only when receiving the string in the string variable "results"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you structure your classes like this, using the JsonProperty to map the properties, it could work:

```vb
Public Class MetaData

    <JsonProperty("1. Information")>
    Public Property Information As String

    <JsonProperty("2. Symbol")>
    Public Property Symbol As String

    <JsonProperty("3. Last Refreshed")>
    Public Property LastRefreshed As String

    <JsonProperty("4. Output Size")>
    Public Property OutputSize As String

    <JsonProperty("5. Time Zone")>
    Public Property TimeZone As String

End Class

Public Class TimeSeriesData
    
    <JsonProperty("1. open")>
    Public Property Open As Decimal

    <JsonProperty("2. high")>
    Public Property High As Decimal

    <JsonProperty("3. low")>
    Public Property Low As Decimal

    <JsonProperty("4. close")>
    Public Property Close As Decimal

    <JsonProperty("5. volume")>
    Public Property Volume As Integer

End Class
```

With the classes setup, you would then parse the respective objects by using DeserializeObject:

```vb
Dim obj = JObject.Parse(results)
Dim meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MetaData)(obj.First.First.ToString())
Dim dailyTimeSeries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of DateTime, TimeSeriesData))(obj.Last.First.ToString())
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R1WXok